# Table with less cells than columns

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with a dynamic number of table cells that needs to always be three columns, even if there are only 2 table cells. When I have 2 table cells, even if I give them a set width, they always expand to fill the row and it ends up being a 2 column table. I need the table to appear as though there is an empty third table cell without actually having an empty cell. Is this possible?

I cannot use Javascript.

```html
<table style="width:100%;margin:0;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height:1in;page-break-inside:avoid;margin:0;">
      <td colspan="4" class="col-xs-4" style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
          <div style="height:1in;padding:10px;">
            <span>Cell text</span>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="4" class="col-xs-4" style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
          <div style="height:1in;padding:10px;">
            <span>Cell text</span>
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: remove your colspan="4" and you can add empty <td></td> and it will take up a cell space in that position

Comment: You could add a blank `<td>` at the end (`<td></td>`)

Comment: I cannot add a blank <td> as the # of <td> is dynamic and ideally there would always be three, but sometimes there will only be two

Comment: you say dynamic but also say you can't use javascript? only way to fix this is to have a table cell element take up that spot otherwise you get into a deep mess of other elements (div) and convoluted css to make that space.